# How to make my code more Pythonic?

Tags: python

I try to define a function as short as possible, and the function to return True if `test` is always true, and false if there is some value for which it is false. I tried so:

```
def res(v): for d in List: return True if v.test(d) else: pass
```

It does not work. How to define such a function ?

I want to define it on only one line.

---

Comment: Are you playing code golf? Otherwise there's absolutely no reason to "define a function as short as possible"

Comment: I want to gain experience with Python in the same time as working.

Comment: I knew it was possible, but I did not manage to do it. so i asked.

Comment: @alinsoar: experience in Python will lead you to write Pythonic code, which is readable rather than small.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What about:

```
res = lambda x: all(test(v) for v in x)
```

Or

```
res = lambda x: all(map(test, x))
```

---

As mentionned by [Vladimir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/234745/vladimir) in the comments, your `test` is actually a method of an object called `v`, so it should actually be:

```
lambda v: all(map(v.test, List)) # You should not use List as a variable name!
```

You probably would like to pass the `List` as an argument too though.

---

Have a look at the [documentation for the `all` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all), the [one for the `map` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) and [`lambda` functions](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#lambda).

Comment: nice :) It was exactly what I wanted :). thanks.

Comment: you don't need that pair of brackets around generator.

Comment: @RomanBodnarchuk That's `True`!

Comment: Its not entirely clear from the question, but as far as I can tell it be `any` rather than `all`

Comment: @aquavitae The original post says "false if there is some value for which it is false", so I guess it's actually `all` : ).

Comment: It should be `lambda v: all(map(v.test, List))` to be more precise.

Comment: Yes, the transformation test => v.test was directly, as time as I knew about `all`.

Comment: Also, list comprehensions are good too! (and I find more readable): `lambda v: all([v.test(each) for each in List])`

Comment: @HenryGomersall That's true! However, `lambda x: all(test(v) for v in x)` is a generator expression, it does something similar, but can only be used once. The upside is that is avoids the memory overhead of creating a `List`. They are generally useful when you would use a list comprehension, but will only use it once. : )

Comment: @ThomasOrozco Even better! :) (I went to add my comment I think before you updated the post)

Comment: @ThomasOrozco Ah yes, I see now.  The code posted looks like `any` though.  And that's exactly why forcing something onto one line purely for the sake of brevity is bad!

Answer (score 1):

This is closer to what you want:

```
def res(v, values):
    return all(v.test(d) for d in values)
```

This would also work:

```
def res(v, values):
    return filter(v.test, values) == values
```

As mentioned above, don't name your variable `list`.